# Scrolling PDFs in iOS with iFrame

Tags: java, html, ios, pdf, scroll

I'm trying to scroll this pdf: ifcharts.ml/KSAN.html

I've got this so far:

```
  <section class="features section-padding" id="features">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="feature-list">
                <h3>San Diego</h3>
                <p>Departure</p>
                  <div>
                  <iframe class="js/scroll-wrapper.js" src="http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/SAN/APD/AIRPORT+DIAGRAM/pdf" width="600" height="700"></iframe>
                    <iframe class="js/scroll-wrapper.js" src="https://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KSAN/DP/all/pdf" width="600" height="700"></iframe>
                  </div>
                <p>Approach</p>
                  <div>
                    <iframe class="js/scroll-wrapper.js" src="https://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KSAN/STAR/all/pdf" width="600" height="700"></iframe>
                    <iframe class="js/scroll-wrapper.js" src="https://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KSAN/IAP/all/pdf" width="600" height="700"></iframe>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
      </div>
   </section>
```

The class="js/scroll-wrapper.js" leads to this:

```
 .scroll-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll-wrapper iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

That is what the the script is meant to run, however it still is not scrolling on iOS.

I also have a problem where it is downloading the code on Android. How can I set it now to download?

Thanks

Comment: I think your question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46707431/7818637

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iframe scroll When PDf is loaded on ios device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707431/iframe-scroll-when-pdf-is-loaded-on-ios-device)